# What is a good alternative to this C++17 fold expression in C++14?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, fold-expression

Here is a nice, succinct fold expression based lambda in C++17:

```
#include <cstdint>

using ::std::uint64_t;

constexpr auto sumsquares = [](auto... n) { return ((n * n) + ...); };

// I want this to work.
uint64_t foo(uint64_t x, uint64_t y, uint64_t z)
{
    return sumsquares(x, y, z);
}
// And this too
double bar(uint64_t x, double y)
{
    return sumsquares(x, y);
}
```

I have this code I've written to do something similar in C++14, but it seems a lot more verbose and confusing than it should be. I'm looking for a way to express the above C++17 code in C++14 in a way that's relatively clear and succinct.  To be precise, I want to be able to write code that computes the square of the magnitude of a vector for a vector of some known number of dimensions with a function-call like syntax. The number of dimensions may vary arbitrarily though. And the precise numeric type of the individual components of the coordinate system may also be arbitrary and possibly heterogeneous. But a general way to handle C++17 fold expressions in C++14 would be ideal.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility> 

using ::std::uint64_t;

namespace {
    static constexpr struct {
        template <typename T>
        auto operator()(T && n) const
        {
           return n*n;
        }
        template <typename T, typename... S>
        auto operator()(T && n, S && ... s) const
        {
            return (n * n) + (*this)(::std::forward<S>(s)...);
        }
    } sumsquares;
}

// I want this to work.
uint64_t foo(uint64_t x, uint64_t y, uint64_t z)
{
    return sumsquares(x, y, z);
}
// And this too
double bar(uint64_t x, double y)
{
    return sumsquares(x, y);
}
```

Comment: What's it supposed to do?

Comment: @NeilButterworth - I want to be able to express computing the sum of the squares of an arbitrary number of number-like objects with a succinct function-call like syntax. Each time I need this sum, I do know how many numbers I'll be working with at that particular time. And I want the compiler to generate code for this that's as efficient as possible. :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious I think the right place for your question is: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: @eyllanesc - Yeah, I was wondering if that wasn't a better place. :-/

Comment: You can smash the arguments into an array of their common type and use a conventional loop over that to compute the result.

Comment: @eyllanesc - I think I've re-written the question to be more appropriate for StackOverflow. And I also re-worded the question such that I suspect people will more commonly find it to be a useful search result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template<class F, class A0>
auto fold(F&&, A0&& a0) {
    return std::forward<A0>(a0);
}

template<class F, class A0, class...As>
auto fold(F&& f, A0&&a0, As&&...as) {
    return f(std::forward<A0>(a0), fold(f, std::forward<As>(as)...));
}

auto sum_squares=[](auto&&...args) {
    return fold(std::plus<>{}, (args * args)... );
};
```

Comment: I think not quite right. `return f(std::forward<A0>(a0),fold(std::forward<As>(as)...));` should read  `return f(std::forward<A0>(a0),fold(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<As>(as)...));`. But, otherwise, this is my new favorite. It provides a way to translate almost any case fold expression into C++14.

Comment: @omni sorry, was typing it during opening credits of a movie; didn't compile it.  Will try to fix it.  Ok fixed; movie over.  Should be right or left fold, but I didn't want to be wrong, and would need to examine definitions to be certain.

Comment: Does this solution pattern have a name?

Comment: @solico Can you guess its name from the function name?

Answer (score 8):

A possible not-recursive way to write `sum()` is the following

```
template <typename ... Ts>
auto sum (Ts ... ts)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   std::common_type_t<Ts...>  ret {};

   (void)unused{ 0, (ret += ts, 0)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

Given a `sum()` function, `sum_of_squares()` can be simply written as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
auto sum_of_squares (Ts ... ts)
 { return sum( (ts*ts)... ); }
```

Comment: One problem with this is the return type. It assumes that the type of the first argument is the appropriate return type, which it may not be in the case of heterogeneous types.

Comment: @Omnifarious - you're right; what about using `std::common_type`? Answer modified.

Comment: I think your method to avoid recursion is definitely interesting (that's also the first time I see it), however [it seems to lead to less optimal assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/5a584j), and personally I find it a bit less readable

Comment: @Synxis - it's a very common method, specially developing C++14 `constexpr` variadic template functions (in C++11 can't be used for `constexpr` functions, in C++17 if often substituted with template folding). But I'm agree: it's a bit less readable. Regarding optimal assembly... interesting; I didn't know. But, maybe, this can depend from specific compiler.

Comment: I don't highly value removal of recursion as a path to readability. I find Haskell to be completely unreadable, but that's because of the complete lack of any kind of punctuation, not because of the recursion. I find Scheme fairly readable, and it uses recursion just as much. I think learning to read recursive things is a core skill that should be expected of programmers at intermediate and above skill levels.

Comment: What's the purpose of the leading `0, ` in the list?

Comment: Oh, it's so that the array can never be of 0 length.  nm.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do simpler and more generic actually, by defining a generic sum over several objects:

```
template<typename T>
T sum(T x)
{
    return x;
}
template<typename U, typename... T>
auto sum(U x, T... nums)
{
    return x + sum(nums...);
}

template<typename... T>
auto sum_of_squares(T... nums)
{
    auto square = [](auto x) { return x * x; };
    return sum(square(nums)...);
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7140616b8ca0c819), and [here](https://godbolt.org/g/5a584j) you can see the generated assembly (which seems optimal). Although I personally really dislike `auto` as return type, here it allows to avoid a very complex expression to get the type.

Comment: That is definitely better. Thank you.

Comment: And I agree with you about `auto`. But, part of the reason I wrote the original C++17-only fold expression-based lambda was to see how many times I could use `auto` in an expression and have it actually be the right thing to do. :-)