# Mysterious C++ variadic template expansion

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

The following C++ function is extracted from lines 151 - 157 [here](https://github.com/colmap/colmap/blob/dev/src/util/misc.h):

```
template <typename... T>
std::string JoinPaths(T const&... paths) {
  boost::filesystem::path result;
  int unpack[]{0, (result = result / boost::filesystem::path(paths), 0)...};
  static_cast<void>(unpack);
  return result.string();
}
```

The function `JoinPaths("foo", "bar", "doo.txt")` will return a `std::string` with value `"foo/bar/doo.txt"` (I think) so I understand the semantics of the function.

I am trying to understand the two lines before the `return` statement. `unpack` in an array of `int`s, but what (and why) is happening with the leading 0's and the ellipses at the end. Can someone explain how this gets expanded? Why the 0's? I assume the `static_cast` is there to keep the compiler from optimizing away the array?

Comment: What part of the expansion do you not understand? Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680461/variadic-template-pack-expansion) explains it?

Comment: Yes ... thanks ... the answer explaining the dummy array makes sense.... so the `static_cast` is to avoid optimization that would thow the array out?

Comment: @wcochran, no, just to suppress the warning about unused variable (array in that case).

Comment: @TedLyngmo is there a way to see the compiler's expansion? What is weird is that `unpack` is an array of `int`s ... it must be the clever use of the comma operator with the second 0...

Comment: It could be array of anything really, int is just a generic dummy type. Comma just returns whatever's to its right hand side, dummy 0 in this case, this way one can have functions returning void being called on array initialization. Again, see @1201ProgramAlarm link.

Comment: BTW, you may also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51006031/4885321). tldr: the code you've posted is a pre-C++17 workaround for the lack of fold expressions in the language.

Comment: @wcochran I misunderstood the question at first and removed the comment. Yes, the second `0` is just to discard `something` in `(something, 0)` and let the result be an `int`. The first `0` is to not try to create a zero-sized array in case one calls the function without arguments

Comment: post C++17 you could just fold a comma operator expression right?
i.e. `(result = result / boost::filesystem::path(paths), ... )`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int unpack[]{0, (result = result / boost::filesystem::path(paths), 0)...};
```

The first `0` is there to not try to create an empty array if someone calls the function with zero arguments.

```
(result = result / boost::filesystem::path(paths), 0)
```

This evaluates `result = result / boost::filesystem::path(paths)` and discards it. The result is the `0` to the right side of the comma.

`...` is a *pack expansion*, putting a `,` between each, making it into:

```
int unpack[]{0, (result = result / boost::filesystem::path("foo"),0), 
                (result = result / boost::filesystem::path("bar"),0),
                (result = result / boost::filesystem::path("doo.txt"),0)
            };
```

So, there will be four `0`:s in `unpack`. The cast afterwards is just to disable the warning about the unused variable `unpack`.

Since C++17:

`[[maybe_unused]] int unpack ...` could be used instead to remove the warning. One could also use a *fold expression* and *constexpr if* to skip the `unpack` variable completely - and one could use `std::filesystem` instead of the `boost::filesystem`:

```
template<class... Ps>
std::string JoinPaths2(Ps&&... paths) {
    std::filesystem::path result;
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ps)) // can't unfold empty expansion over /
        result = (std::filesystem::path(std::forward<Ps>(paths)) / ...);
    return result.string();
}
```

Comment: This sounds almost idiomic ... first time I have ran into it.,

Comment: @wcochran Fold expressions? Yeah, it's a nice feature.

Answer (score 4):

As already noted while I was typing this up, it is a pre-C++17 method to perform a [**fold expression**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

It uses a local temporary array of int, along with the comma operator, to sneak a bunch of what would otherwise be:

```
result = result / paths[n]
```

into an integer expression, ultimately producing:

```
int unpack[]{
  0, 
  (result = result / paths[0], 0),
  (result = result / paths[1], 0),
  ...,
  (result = result / paths[N], 0)
};
```

These days, the following will do:

```
template <typename...Pathnames>
std::string JoinPaths( Pathnames...pathnames )
{
  return (std::filesystem::path( pathnames ) / ...).string();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... It would be worth mentioning the two uses of 0's -- one to avoid an empty array and one for the comma operator so that a result of type int is produced...