# How to expand the parameter package without recursion and not decomposing the elements into an array?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class... Other>
auto sum(T& first, Other... other)
{
    T mas[] = { other... };
    cout << "size: " << sizeof...(other) << endl;
    //T *f = other...;
    for (int m : mas)
        first += m;
    return first;
}

int main()
{
    int summa = 0;
    sum(summa, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    cout << "sum: " << summa << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There is a short piece of code that outputs the following:

```
size: 7
sum: 28
```

The question is very simple and quick to get the same answer:
How do I access element by element each variable accounting parameter `other`? I tried to create a pointer, but it constantly complains, in short, I don’t know how it looks syntactically.

I will make a reservation right away that I am not interested in how to decompose the elements into an array, I myself know how exactly I should refer to each element exactly other.

**More precisely, how to expand the parameter package without recursion and not decomposing the elements into an array?**

Comment: Well, you expand the pack with `...`. What specifically do you want to do with it?

Comment: access the first element, then the second, and so on. not using an array

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?  C++17 provides ways to do this without recursion.

Answer (score 3):

> How to expand the parameter package without recursion?

You have since C++17-[fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) for this needs.
Using it, your function will simply be

```
template <class T, class... Other>
auto sum(T& first, const Other&... other)
{
    first = (other + ... + first);
    return first;
}
```

or without the redundant variable `summa` may be:

```
#include <type_traits>  // std::common_type_t

template <class... Other>
constexpr auto sum(const Other&... other) /* noexcept */
{
    return (other + ... + std::common_type_t<Other...>{});
}
```

**[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pnr7cMccs)**

---

> How do I access element by element each variable accounting parameter `other`?

You can apply fold expression along with [an immediately invoking lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868369/how-to-immediately-invoke-a-c-lambda) as follows:

```
template <typename ReType, typename... Other>
auto do_something_with_args(ReType& ret, Other&&... other)
{
    ([&ret](auto /* const& */ arg) {
        // do something with each arg and ret
        ret += arg; // example
        std::cout << arg << '\n';
        }(std::forward<Other>(other)), ...);
    return ret;
}
```

**[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e8PvbEYzh)**

---

If you do not have access to C++17, then there are tweaks/ alternatives, which have been mentioned in the following posts:

- [What is a good alternative to this C++17 fold expression in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005897/what-is-a-good-alternative-to-this-c17-fold-expression-in-c14)
- [How to call a function on all variadic template args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339789/how-to-call-a-function-on-all-variadic-template-args)

Comment: I don’t want to implement it this way, I need to access it element by element, for this I need to receive data for each element separately

Comment: Elements may not match in type, this function is just an example to make it clear what I need

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?

```
template <class T, class... Other>
auto sum(T& first, Other... other)
{
    std::apply([&first](auto &&... i){(..., (first += i)); }, std::make_tuple(std::forward<Other>(other)...));
    return first;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to access an element without intermediate actions?

Comment: @Fedor you can get access every item via **i** without intermediate actions.

Comment: @JeJo yes, you are right, I agree with you.